# Python WebBrowser Open In Same Tab

Tags: python-webbrowser

running this line:

```
webbrowser.open(page.path, new=0, autoraise=True)
```

I always get the page opened in a new Tab.

How can I get it in the same Tab as it should be using new=0?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done unfortunately.

You can set the variable to whatever you want but browser tab behaviour is hard-set in modern browsers and will override it.  You'll find that you won't be able to use new=1 to open in a brand new window either, for the same reason.  It will always just be a new tab.

The last update to the webbrowser module in the [Github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/webbrowser.py) was about the same age as this question, I wonder if this has been abandoned.